# How to tap buttons or images without selecting the whole cell with Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tableview

I'm using a custom `TableViewCell` in my iOS app. I use the method `tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath` to open a new `ViewController`. What I need to do is to add a button or an image somewhere in the custom cell so if I tap the button or whatever element don't open the `ViewController`, but execute a function without opening the cell.

Comment: it can be done easily share what you have done yet so we can help

Comment: Adding an @IBAction for your button doesn't works?

Comment: use @IBAction  and set tags to the button then find out the pressed button.

Comment: If you are using CustomCell in Storyboard just add a button on CustomCell & implement "TouchUpInside" method. You can create & add button on cell by coding in "CellForRowAtIndexPath" and for button add a selector from "addTarget......" method.

Comment: okay many thanks to all of you. I'll give it a try I'll post if I wasn't able

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `[cell.button setTag:indexPath.row]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

and than `addTarget` to `cell.button` like

`[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]];`

and than do Whatever you want to do in `yourAction`

with getting tag from sender.

Or you want code for that than please add your code what you had done so we can help more if you are new in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

This code may helps you

here i have used custom buttom in table and add target to that buton

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{


    let cell: AnyObject = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // use your custom cell here



    //cell = UIColor.redColor()


    //cell.textLabel?!.text = String(data[indexPath.row])

    //nameTextField.text = ""

    let custom_btn : UIButton? = UIButton.init(type: .System)
    //declaring custom button

    custom_btn?.setTitle("custom button", forState: .Normal)

    custom_btn!.tag = indexPath.row

    custom_btn!.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    cell .addSubview(custom_btn!);

    return cell as! UITableViewCell
}



func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    if(sender.tag == 5){

       //Do something for tag
    }
    print("hello")
}
```